# Codeception dump not running

Tags: mysql, testing, codeception

Hi i try to run a dump sql. It is working fine on cli

```
    actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
#        - Codeception\Lib\Driver\Db
modules:
    enabled: [Db]
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'mypass'
            dump: codeception/_data/dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
```

How can i debug it?

Comment: Move enabled: [Db] to suite.yml

Comment: Ok that was it thank you